# Find Top Tags Except the Following

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, hash, except

I'd to find the top 5 used tags, while excluding those tags with certain names. I still would like to return 5, and not just delete elements from the hash. Without the exception the code works fine:

```
def self.trending
  Tag.select("tags.id, tags.name,count(taggings.tag_id) as count").joins(:taggings).group("taggings.tag_id, tags.id, tags.name").order("count DESC").limit(5)
end
```

Can I create an array with the names I don't want, and except those from the select? This is not working.

```
def self.trending
  exclude = ["boring", "notworthy"]
  Tag.select("tags.id, tags.name,count(taggings.tag_id) as count").except(name: exclude).joins(:taggings).group("taggings.tag_id, tags.id, tags.name").order("count DESC").limit(5)
end
```

Comment: Please use includes avoid joins, it will result in n+1 queries.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SashantPardeshi but I'm not sure I understand. You mean to remove the joins function?

Comment: @robinyapockets see includes vs joins in rails doc page, but it seems you should use arel to generate the query, it allows the form like `where(value.not_in(array))`

Comment: Which rails version are you using btw?

Comment: Thanks @МалъСкрылевъ I will look into it!

Comment: @HoangPhan I'm using 4.1.4

Comment: Then you could use `where.not` instead of except (https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activerecords-wherenot)

Comment: Thanks @HoangPhan ! That works! However only with using joins(:taggings). If I use include I get a the error: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: taggings.tag_id: SELECT  tags.id, tags.name,count(taggings.tag_id) as count FROM "tags"  WHERE ("tags"."name" NOT IN ('boring', 'notworthy')) GROUP BY taggings.tag_id, tags.id, tags.name  ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 6:

Comment: It is because includes does not actually join the two table, it uses to preload the association, so with includes the query can only know tags' attributes, not taggings'. To actually left join the two table you could use includes(:taggings).references(:taggings) or eager_load(:taggings)